# What does subwcrev need?

Tags: svn, ant, build

I wrote a build script in ant. The source code of my project is versioned in svn.

As a part of my project I had to write a java class, that contains information from subversion. In general, the build script works fine. All needed information will be gathered, except one. This is the name of the author who commited the last change in the reporsitory. Though I read the [manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev-com-interface.html), I still come up with any ideas.

My question to you is: does exist a way to get also this detail with an ant script?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

```
<target name="version" description="set version number">
    <echo message="Setting version information ..." />
    <copy file="build/Version.java.template"
        tofile="./cq/apps/src/de/anna/util/Version.java" /> 
    <tstamp>
        <format property="TODAY_De"
         pattern="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
         locale="de,De"/>
    </tstamp>
    <replace file="./cq/apps/src/de/anna/util/Version.java">
        <replacefilter token="@APPNAME@" value="${app.name}" />
        <replacefilter token="@BUILDVERSION@" value="${build.number}" />
        <replacefilter token="@BUILDDATE@" value="${TODAY_De}" />
    </replace>
    <exec executable="${version.tool}" spawn="false" dir=".">
        <arg line=". cq/apps/src/de/anna/Util/Version.java cq/apps/src/de/anna/Util/Version.java" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

What I want to add in file Version.java, who is the author of last commit and the id of the change entry. (I think/thought $Author$ and $Id$ were the variables)

Comment: Are you calling the SubWCRev command line program from ANT?  One approach would be write a properties file from the information you gathered in ANT, and have a Java class that reads the properties file. However, I'm not clear on what you need help with or if this is what you are intending to do...can you post some of your ANT script?

Comment: Hello, I haven't expected a reaction after this long time yet :-). But I updated my initial post. Hopefully it will help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget about SubWCRev and think about Subversion. That's what your working with.

In Subversion, you need to set a property called `svn:keywords`, and set that value to the keywords you want to use. This is explained in the on line Subversion manual in [Keyword Substitution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html).

By using the `svn:keywords` property, you have the Subversion repository handle the variable names for you. For example, you have a file called `information.txt` that looks like this:

```
The last person to check in the file is $Author$ and the last version was $Version$.
```

Checking that file into Subversion doesn't change `$Author$` or `$Revision$`.

Now, you set the property `svn:keywords` on the `information.txt` file:

```
$ svn propset svn:keywords "Author Date" information.txt
$ svn commit -m"Setting svn:keywords to set the information in information.txt"
```

You can do this through TortoiseSVN too via the Context Menu *TortoiseSVN*-->*Properties*

Now, when you look at the file, the fields changed:

```
$ cat information.txt
The last person to check in the file is $Author:David$ and the last version was $Revision:123$.
```

Not what you want? Another thing you can do is simply execute `svn info` and get the properties you want in XML format. Then you can use the `<xmlProperties>` task to read them in as properties:

```
<project>
    <property name="target.dir" value="${basedir}/target"/>

    <mkdir dir="${target.dir}"/>
    <exec executable="svn"
        outputProperty="svn.info">
        <arg line="info --xml"/>
    </exec>
    <echo message="${svn.info}"
        file="${target.dir}/info.txt"/>
    <xmlproperty file="${target.dir}/info.txt"
        keeproot="no"
        prefix="svn"/>
    <echo message="Author = &quot;${svn.entry.commit.author}&quot;"/>
    <echo message="Date = &quot;${svn.entry.commit.date}&quot;"/>
    <echo message="Revision = &quot;${svn.entry(revision)}&quot;"/>
</project>
```

I use the `<exec>` task to grab the Subversion information and put it in the property `${svn.info}`. I then use the `<echo>` task to output it to the `${target.dir}/info.txt` file. After that, I can read the file via the `<xmlproperty>` task and pull out the information below.

From there, I now have all the Subversion revision and repository information stored in various properties.

If you know resource collections, you can actually do this without first writing the file to `${target}/info.txt`

```
<project>
    <exec executable="svn"
        outputProperty="svn.info">
        <arg line="info --xml"/>
    </exec>

    <xmlproperty keeproot="no"
        prefix="svn">
        <propertyresource name="svn.info"/>
    </xmlproperty>

    <echo message="Author = &quot;${svn.entry.commit.author}&quot;"/>
    <echo message="Date = &quot;${svn.entry.commit.date}&quot;"/>
    <echo message="Revision = &quot;${svn.entry(revision)}&quot;"/>
</project>
```

Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try it out, but I need more time (at the moment I'm working in a project). PS: What I forgot to mention is, I need these information to display it in a webpage, that's why I want to use a java class.

Comment: I think the concept still applies...use keyword expansion to get the version, author into a file that a Java program can easily read out--like XML or a properties file.